# You don't have permission to access / on this server docker

Tags: docker

I want to start a container from that image:

sudo docker run --name phpldapadmin   -p 2222:80 -p 2443:443  -e LDAP_HOST=ldap.example.com  -e LDAP_LOGIN_DN=cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com --link openldap:ldap-host  --detach osixia/phpldapadmin:0.7.0 --copy-service

But when I'm visiting my localhost:2222 I see:

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
So my question is: How do I have to start my container properly? What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Have a look at the [openldap quick start](https://github.com/osixia/docker-phpLDAPadmin#quick-start), it seems that you need to forward to port 443, not 80, so maybe try to change your command to `... -p 2222:443 ...`

Comment: tanks, with this guide i acces to panel but geberate 3 error in panel : Error: Could not start TLS. Please check your LDAP server configuration. and  Error: Can't contact LDAP server (-1) for user and nvalid Username or Password.